# Intuitive answer needed for the condition on the sets to be convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have read that an optimization problem is convex if the objective function is convex and if all the constraints define convex sets. Is there any intuitive reasoning for sets to be convex? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it's nice? If a convex optimization problem is _defined_ as one where the function and the set are both convex, then that's kind of arbitrary, just like most definitions. Presumably it just turned out to be a good balance between assuming too much (so the theory never becomes applicable) and assuming too little (so you can't get any general results).

Comment: @Arthur many thanks for your comment. But I am unable to understand what it means. Can you please explain your comment in easy way?

Comment: I am lost by the question: "intuitive reasoning for sets to be convex"? Are you looking for sufficient conditions for convexity? The first sentence is just the definition of a convex optimization problem.

Comment: What I mean is, there is (probably) no objective reason it should be defined that way. It turned out to work nicely, so mathematicians liked it and kept using it until it was standard. That's how most conventional definitions come to be, so I assume it was the case here as well.

Comment: @max_zorn I mean why the sets defined by constraints has to be convex sets in a convex optimization problem? What will happen if we have non-convex sets as results of constraints?

Comment: @Arthur thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @FrankMoses OK - convex optimization problems have a rich developed theory and algorithms. If you have a nonconvex problem, then these are generally much harder to solve.

Comment: Not just "much harder", but _theoretically intractable_.

Comment: Nitpicking: A problem being convex does not necessarily mean the problem is tractable. There are convex problems which are very hard (optimization over the co-positive cone is one such example). It has to be "easy" to check if a point is in the convex set, and that is not necessarily the case. Similarily, there are nonconvex problems that are easy to solve. Rule of thumb though is convex easy nonconvex hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convexity allows one to conclude *global* optimality from *local* optimality. Local optimality can be concluded using only **local information** such as the gradient and the Hessian.

In computer science, the equivalent to the class of (continuous) convex optimization problems is arguably the class of (discrete) optimization problems that can be solved using [greedy algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) (which also use only local information). You may want to take a look at [greedoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid).